Does Kalki Avatar come in this Kali Yuga (28th one) or on the ending of 71st Kali Yuga?
We are living in Kali-yuga of the 28th Chatur-yuga cycle of 7th Manvantara. So in which kali yuga does Lord Kalki come? in this kali yuga or the last kali yuga(71st)? so if Kalki avatar does come in this Kali-yuga, how does this Manvantara end? also if Kalki avatar comes in this Kali-yuga then why is this Chatur yuga so special that the supreme lord took three avatars of dasavatars in this chaturyuga itself.
